# How do I make my wamp icon turn green?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

1) I have installed 32 bit version wamp 2.2E, on windows XP 32bit.  The icon is currently orange. I do not have skype.

2)The windows hosts file does have the line:
    127.0.0.1 localhost

3a) Trying to enter //127.0.0.1/ in the browser results in error:
"Navigation to the webpage cancelled"

3b) or //localhost/ results in error:
"Access denied"

4)Apache and PHP error logs are empty even after restarting services.

5) restarted under services.msc the service "wampmysqld", doesn't help

6) stopping first then restarting all services doesn't help [I should add the icon has never been green from the first installation of wamp has been going to orange]

Comment: Have you right clicked the icon in the notification area and click "Put Online" ?

Comment: Yes it says "WAMPSERVER - server Online" when i mouseover the icon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved:
I downloaded the older version wampserver 2.1e - and bam, it works.
Note: during the installation process, the windows firewall popped up and asked me if I wanted to continue to block certain elements from apache http, I chose unblock, and bam it works!  Now I wonder if that was the problem with 2.2e, if I needed to go into the firewall and something is blocking apache.

Comment: worked for me too for 3+ version, before that i installed all softwares in this world.....

Answer (score 12):

Please note this happens because there is some other application running on port 80 , which is used by wamp.

You can check by wamp-> apache-> service -> Test port 80. It will list out applications used by port 80.

In our case IIS server was running http service, so start task manager, first click show all processess, put a stop to HTTP

After this fix i got IIS page issue on localhost which got solved when we did below step check in your hosts file in WINDOWS folder, if entry 127.0.0.0 localhost is commented then uncomment it by removing # infront of that line.

Comment: Before click on "Restart All Services" make sure all services are installed. You can check by clicking in [wamp icon >> apache >> service administration >> install]. if sertice is not installed, you can install it. using same method, check MySQL and MaridaDB too.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure applications like Yahoo Messenger, Skype, or ICQ are not running when you try to start WAMP. If any of the 3 apps are running, WAMP will fail to start because for some reason they also use the local address. Stop the apps first, restart WAMP, and when it is green, you may restart your IMs. Hope this helps.

Comment: No IMs are running, this computer was just purchased (second hand) but it has a fresh install of XP on it, and wamp is like the second application after Maxthon that I just installed on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can often get stuck in this position when the wamp services are not running correctly. From the start menu run "services.msc" look for any services that mention wamp (sort alphabetical) and ensure they all say "started".

If this still doesn't work try stopping the services for wamp and restarting them, it may take a moment or two for the menus to refresh and work.

Comment: This worked for me. I think I had unknowingly stopped the services while trying to speed up my computer earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had disabled all my services. For who is looking for an answer and still have no help, try reopening WAMP, right click and click on start all services.